# How to stop score timer when .... in Lua

Tags: android, timer, lua, coronasdk

Ok, so this is my current score - timer

```
local scoreTxt = display.newText( "Score: 0", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 40 )
scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
scoreTxt.x = display.screenOriginX + 10
scoreTxt.y = display.screenOriginY + 32

local function updateScore()
     score = score + 20
     scoreText.text = string.format("Score: %d", score)
end

local scoreTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, updateScore, 0)
```

I want that timer to pause when

```
function explode()
    exp.x = bird.x
    exp.y = bird.y
    exp.isVisible = true
    exp:play()
    bird.isVisible = false
    timer.performWithDelay(1500, gameOver, 1)
```

After that the game redirects to you died screen, where the score should be visible, but I want it to go back to 0 when

```
function start(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        storyboard.gotoScene("game", "fade", 50)
    end
end
```

So, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
score = 0 -- You need to set the score to 0 everytime you create the game scene
local scoreTxt = display.newText( "Score: 0", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 40 )
scoreTxt:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
scoreTxt.x = display.screenOriginX + 10
scoreTxt.y = display.screenOriginY + 32

local function updateScore()
     score = score + 20
     scoreText.text = string.format("Score: %d", score)
end

local scoreTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, updateScore, 0)

function explode()
    timer.cancel(scoreTimer) --This will cancel the timer and eventually stop
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code Is not clear enough to tell me what's going on, But If you're trying to Ignore what timer does, Do the following way:

```
EnableScoreTimer = true -- Make It Global so you can call It from other files too.

local function updateScore()
     if not EnableScoreTimer then return end
     score = score + 20
     scoreText.text = string.format("Score: %d", score)
end

local scoreTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, updateScore, 0)
```

This way creates a bool to check when to disable the timer or not, It doesn't end the timer but It just makes It to not run the other actions. Whenever you want to turn the score timer off Just use a simple true/false check to turn It on / off.

```
function explode()
    EnableScoreTimer = false
```

Comment: Ok, but the timer still stays there, and then a new one displays over the cancelled one...

Comment: @user2735374 It's a good Idea to use Raymle's answer, I haven't worked with corona yet but That's a normal way on lua that you can easily get ride of something, This method works perfect on computer because computer got better system than a mobile, So not good Idea to have many of these on mobile.